# When to retrieve data from from EditText and copy to the clipboard for the user to obtain?

Tags: android, android-edittext, clipboard, copy-paste, clipboardmanager

I'm developing a clipboard manager app for Android, and it involves retrieving stored data from what the user had previously copied. I want this data to show up when the user hits paste. Does anybody know how I can implement this? My code is provided below.

```
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);

int contentPos = 0;

 do {

                String primaryDataNew = ets.get(contentPos).getText().toString(); //Fetches copied data stored in first EditText position in EditText array list ets from app

                //Copies data to clipboard

                ClipData clipNew = ClipData.newPlainText("Data retrieved: ", primaryDataNew);
                clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clipNew);

                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                System.out.println(primaryDataNew);

                //if... (What?)
                contentPos++;

                //else {}

    } while (contentPos < ets.size());
```

What can I possibly put in the if statement to ensure that the user obtained the retrieve data (most likely via paste) before I can retrieve the data from the next position in ets? I appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have a way to know if data was copied off of the clipboard into any app. In particular, you have no way to know if the user decided to paste something into any app.

Comment: Oh, ok. That's unfortunate. Do you know anything I could use to know when to retrieve the stored data and copy it to the clipboard so that the user can get it when he hits the past button then? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Nisarg I have an idea which you can try. Clipboard functions become active when user do long press on edit text. I think you can track long press event.

Comment: @Aditya: You cannot "track long press event" in other apps.

Comment: Yes, I believe the "track long press event" involves TextWatcher for the EditText. The problem is that you can only implement this in you app itself. Do you know on what basis could I retrieve the data and copy it to the clipboard: what would be such a user action allowing it to work? Thanks.